# Como usar pipes para mostrar informacion mediante ngfor en angular

Tags: angular, pipe, ngfor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con angular y necesito mostrar unos datos que tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
 {
    "id": 33,
    "arg": 7,
    "date": "2022-01-31",
    "User": {
        "Name": "Cristian",
        "Group": {
            "NGroup": "Group 1"
        }
    },
    "Sport": {
        "NSport": "Sport 1"
    }
},
```

La idea es mostrar la información de esta forma:

`id | arg | date | Name (User) | NGroup (Group) | NSport (Sport)`

Para esto estaba intentando utilizar `keyvalue`, el problema de esto es que cuando trae el objeto User, me muestra un `item` llamado `[object Object]` que corresponde a group y no hay forma de ocultarlo o solo seleccionar que muestre solo nombre. Este es el código actual:

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of listItems">
                      <td><div>{{ item.id }}</div></td>                               
                      <td><div>{{ item.arg}}</div></td>
                      <td><div>{{ item.date }}</div></td>
                      <td *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue "><div>{{ key.value }}</div></td>
                      <td *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue"><div *ngFor="let key2 of key.value | keyvalue" >{{ key2.value }}</div></td>                         
                      <td *ngFor="let kv of item.Sports | keyvalue"><div>{{kv.value}}</div></td>                         
                   
                    </tr>  
                  </tbody>
```

La salida de esto es :

`id | arg | date | [Object,Object] | Name(User) | NGroup (Group) | NSport(sport)`

Claramente el `keyvalue`  está mostrando todo. Investigando me di cuenta que se pueden hacer pipes para mostrar la información de forma personalizada y la verdad no entiendo mucho como funciona, **ese es el motivo de esta pregunta.**

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ingresar directamente a los datos con la notación de puntos sin necesidad del pipe:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of listItems">
      <td>
        <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>{{ item.arg }}</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>{{ item.date }}</div>
      </td>
      <td >
        <div>{{ item.User.Name}}</div>
      </td>
      <td >
        {{ item.User.Group.NGroup }}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Sport.NSport}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Te dará el siguiente resultado:

```
33 7 2022-01-31 Cristian Group 1    Sport 1
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b5p7tw?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer items no necesitas keyvalue simplemente lo podes hacer con simple notacion de puntos  pero entiendo que consultas como
transformar un objeto en un array de pares key-value
y consultas sobre el objeto **item.User** y el objeto **item.Sport**
Como KeyValue Pipe convierte un objeto o mapa dado en una matriz de pares clave-valor. Podemos usar esto con ngFor para para poder recorrer las claves de objeto
Pero en tu caso el objeto es complejo  por eso al  querer ver el valor de una clave te puede mostrar **[object Object]**  ya que alguna clable puede apuntar a un objeto asi que podemos utilizar a  un index para posicionarnos de forma adecuada para distinguir las claves del objeto

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td><div>
      id:{{ item.id }}</div></td>                               
    <td><div>
    arg:  {{ item.arg}}</div></td>
    <td><div>
    date:  {{ item.date }}</div></td>
    <td *ngFor="let i = index;let user of item.User| keyvalue :returnZero">
      <div *ngIf="i==0">
        | {{user.key}} is {{user.value}}
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let group of user.value | keyvalue :returnZero"  >
        <div> |{{group.value}}</div>
      </div>
    </td>                         
  <td *ngFor="let sport of item.Sport | keyvalue :returnZero">
    <div>
      |{{sport.value}}</div>
  </td> 
               
</tr>  
</tbody>
```

Agregue Name porque representa visualmente mejor a cada objeto segun me parece

> id:33 arg: 7 date: 2022-01-31 | Name is Cristian |Group 1 |Sport 1

---

> id:34 arg: 8 date: 2022-04-31 | Name is fernamdo |Group 2 |Sport 2

Ademas te retornaria por default un ordenamiento determinado lo cual  hay que   modificar  para que mantenga el ordenamiento del objeto como muestra el resultado anterior lo hacemos con el siguiente metodo

```js
returnZero() {
  return 0
}
```

Utilidades de su uso
[la utilidad de usar keyvalue](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-keyvalue-pipe-loop-object-key-values-using-ngfor/)

Sobre el orden en que responde
[orden de la respuesta](https://www.elite-corner.com/2020/03/angular-keyvalue-pipe-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hola desconozco para qué quieres usar los pipes si es para filtrar en angular te recomiendo este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-bgl1j1P_4) en español en angular 11 para que conozcas cómo manejar los Pipes;

Pero si lo que necesitas es hacer el muestreo de la información pues estabas bien solo te faltaba el acomodo

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of listItems">
        <td>
            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>{{ item.arg}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>{{ item.date }}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Name: {{ item.User.Name }}</div>
            <div>
                Groups: {{item.User.Group.NGroup}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Sports: {{item.Sport.NSport}}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

y Por resultado sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]